# Java throws Java NullPointerException when making Token

Tags: java, arrays, shapes

Running my program throws A Null Pointer Exception every time I create a new token of a specific type.
 Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Pattern.draw(Pattern.java:98)
at GameToken.draw(GameToken.java:68)
at GameTokenPanel.paintComponent(GameTokenPanel.java:83)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here are the parts in the class which are affected by utoken0.draw(g2) and utoken1.draw(g2);
Here's my pattern class

```
public class Pattern 
{
public static final int pattern0=0;
public static final int pattern1=1;
public static final int pattern2=2;
//private CrossPattern pattern1;
//private LineMid pattern3;
//private CircPattern pattern2;
private Rectangle bbox;
private int type;
private Random random = new Random();
private CrossPattern cross;
private CircPattern circ;
private LineMid linemid;





public Pattern(int type, Rectangle bbox)
{
  this.bbox=bbox;
  type=type;

  if (type == 0) 
  {
    cross= new CrossPattern(bbox);  
  }
  if( type == 1)
  {
  circ=new CircPattern(bbox);     
  }
  if(type ==2)
  {
linemid=new LineMid(bbox); 
  }
  }

  public int getType()
  {
  return type;
  }






public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
 {

  if(type==pattern0)
 cross.draw(g2);
  else   if(type==pattern1)
circ.draw(g2);
  else if (type==pattern2)
      linemid.draw(g2);
 }
 }
```

Here is my GameToken Class:

```
public class GameToken implements VisibleShape
{
private boolean visible;
public  Rectangle bbox;
private Pattern pattern;
private Color color;
Random random = new Random();


 public GameToken(int patternType, int x, int y, int width, int height) 
 {
 bbox = new Rectangle( x,y,width,height);
 if(patternType==0)
 {
    pattern = new Pattern(patternType,bbox);
 }
 else if(patternType==1)
    {
        pattern= new Pattern(patternType,bbox);
    }
 else if(patternType==2)
    {
        pattern = new Pattern(patternType,bbox);
    }
    }






  public  void draw(Graphics2D g2) 
 {
 g2.draw(bbox);
 pattern.draw(g2);


}






}
```

Here is my panel:

```
public class GameTokenPanel extends JPanel {


private GameToken token1;

private final int TOKEN_WIDTH=35;
private Random random = new Random();
private ArrayList <GameToken> tokenarr;
private GameToken utoken0 = new GameToken(0, 0,0,TOKEN_WIDTH,TOKEN_WIDTH);
private GameToken utoken1 = new GameToken(1, 0,0,TOKEN_WIDTH,TOKEN_WIDTH);
private GameToken utoken2 = new GameToken(2, 0,0,TOKEN_WIDTH,TOKEN_WIDTH);
private GameToken currentToken= utoken0;





public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{


super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);

utoken0.draw(g2);
utoken1.draw(g2);
//utoken2.draw(g2);

g2.setColor(Color.RED);
//token1.draw(g2);
for (int i =0; i<=10;i++)
{

tokenarr.get(i).draw(g2);
}



}




 }
```

So basically, I use the panel to create the Game tokens which would create the Pattern and the rectangle. The Pattern class would then call the specific pattern class and draw it using the rectangle dimensions. Which would then appear on a frame.
 The issue is that I would create utoken0 in the panel and draw it in the draw method. But when I would draw utoken1 the same way. It would lead to errors. I initiated them the same way and drew the same way . But I am getting error. Also , if I attempt to draw utoken2, it would also give me an error. 
Also,when I generate the random tokens at the beginning of panel, It creates the 3 types. But when I would run the utoken and pick a specific type. Only the 0 pattern works, however 1 and 2 does not.

Comment: The question has too many scenarios and too much details. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I don't have testing environment, simply dry run on your code.

Your code failure to set correct value into class variable `type` in Pattern. Hence, the `type` variable will have default value `0`.

In draw method of Pattern class, it will call `cross.draw(g2);` since the  `type` is `0`. However, the code never initiate `cross` for pattern 1 or 2. It results in NullPointerException.

You should fix line in Pattern class from:

```
type=type;
```

to

```
this.type=type;
```